# Vim: file system navigation similar to Spacemacs

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm currently going back to Vim from Spacemacs. Is there a plugin that offers a similar way to search / open files? In Spacemacs you can easily navigate the file system after pressing SPC-f-f.

You can see an example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOzzkUjtgZc). I really like how it shows a list of the files and directories under the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live without as-you-type fuzzy-completion, the built-in `:help 'wildmenu'` works beautifully.

If you absolutely *need* as-you-type fuzzy-completion there are many plugins to choose from:

- [Fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)
- [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)
- [Command-t](https://github.com/wincent/command-t)
- [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
- [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim)
- etc.

Comment: Using `<c-d>` and tab completion along with globbing ( e.g. `:e **/*foo.c<tab>`) can get you pretty far without resorting to fuzzy searching.

Comment: I don't need fuzzy-completion, so wildmenu looks interesting, I didn't know about this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @PeterRincker I was wondering if there is a way to use <C-D> automatically, i.e. whenever I press tab to select a directory I'm presented with the contents of this directory, just like when I press <C-D>.

Comment: @matthjes, see `:help 'wildmode'`.